# How to add a simple recaptcha in React Native Application?

Tags: react-native, recaptcha

I make a Phone Authentication page using React-Native and thought that to store the data in firebase so, security purpose I will add a reCaptcha that who fill the reCaptcha they can click the the verify button otherwise no. But when I install this package: npm install react-native-google-recaptcha-v2, I got some error. How can I add reCaptcha ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RKTN.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have used
npm install react-native-google-recaptcha-v2,
so instead of that If you have yarn installed then you can try this
yarn add react-native-google-recaptcha-v2.
Basically, this library is very old so there are version conflicts while using yarn that will manage all things.

react-native-google-recaptcha-v2is a very old library so you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-that-works, maybe this will work for you.

Comment: When I install this: react-native-recaptcha-that-works , the app is not running , I got some error when run : npx react-native start , the error is: error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081. and when I run: npx react-native run-android the error is: > Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Comment: for Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin FAILED –
 run 'npx jetify'

maybe your error will go.

Comment: for  the error is: error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081. 
watch this video in that write  8081 instead of 8080 given in the video. https://youtu.be/3cKbHbFJJ3I

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a project with react version 16.9 and then it works with react-native-google-recaptcha-v2.

react-native-google-recaptcha-v2 lib is too old and not maintained with new React version. You can use latest one **react-native-recaptcha-that-works**.

You can use the latest library

[react-native-recaptcha-that-works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-that-works)

Comment: When I install this: react-native-recaptcha-that-works , the app is not running , I got some error when run : npx react-native start , the error is: error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.   and when I run: npx react-native run-android  the error is: > Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Comment: create a new project and install this lib and then check